# How to convert Pandas dataframe to SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas

want to convert pandas dataframe to sql. I also want to get the `.sql` on my desktop with my sql table.

This is the code that I have:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.DataFrame({'second':[5,6,7,8,9],
                   'first':['ne', 'da', 'ne', 'da', 'da'],
                   'third':[213,151,16,641,64]})

print(df)

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)

sample_sql_database = df.to_sql('sample_database', con=engine)
sample_sql_database = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM sample_database").fetchall()

print(sample_sql_database)
```

Im using `to_sql` , my code does not shows any errors, but I do not know how to get my table to appears on deskop

Comment: Your table is exported to your database called 'sample_database'. You have to query your databse to see the result. You cannot 'open it on your desktop'. Download [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) to query your db.

Answer (score 5):

You can't see it on your desktop because you did not mention correct db_uri. Please mention name atleast after the basic syntax:

```
create_engine('sqlite://** mention name here **', echo=False)
```

This worked for me, try it:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.DataFrame({'second':[5,6,7,8,9],
                   'first':['ne', 'da', 'ne', 'da', 'da'],
                   'third':[213,151,16,641,64]})
print(df)

db_uri = 'sqlite:///file.db'
engine = create_engine(db_uri, echo=False)

sample_sql_database = df.to_sql('sample_database', con=engine)

sample_sql_database = engine.execute("SELECT * FROM sample_database").fetchall()

print(sample_sql_database)
```

Comment: It works, i got the db.sqlite file on deskop, but when I open it on my deskop, its all NULL values, how to see values from datagrame